# How can I get my button to inhabit the center of its cell?

Tags: button, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps, grid-layout

I've got a back button in row 0, col 0 of a grid.

It places itself up at the top of the cell; I want it in the center. I tried setting VerticalAlignment="Center" and that didn't work. Neither did setting it to "Bottom":

```
<Button x:Name="buttonBack" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"></Button>
```

...It doesn't budge a bit. How can I pull it down a scosh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are not setting your row height to Auto sizing.  If use Auto, the BackButtonStyle sets a bottom margin to 36 which make it appear that your button is "pinned" to the top of the row.  It looks like you should be able to "move" it because with the bottom margin space, but you can't because the row is auto sized.

I placed your exact markup with the BackButtonStyle into a grid and I can position it however I want as long as I am using pixel or star sizing on my row.